# How to intercept a call from $http and provide a response accordingly to the type of request?

Tags: angularjs

I've the following piece of code. I declare how and when i pretend to catch a request and respond according to it's body. My problem is that performing the call doesn't resolve the $http and as consequence the .then(...) never fires. 
Am i doing something wrong?

```
 angular.module('app')
        .run(function($http, Appconfig, configMock, $httpBackend){
            var phones = [{name: 'phone1'}, {name: 'phone2'}];




            // returns the current list of phones
            $httpBackend.whenGET('/phones').respond(phones);

            // adds a new phone to the phones array
            $httpBackend.whenPOST('/phones').respond(function(method, url, data) {
                var phone = angular.fromJson(data);
                phones.push(phone);
                console.log('/phones');
                return [200, phone, {}];
            });

            $http({
                url: Appconfig.apiURL,
                method: 'POST',
                API_ACTION: 'foo'
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

            console.log($http({'url':'/phones','method':'POST'}, {'foo':'bar'}).then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }));


        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [AngularJS $http doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#writing-unit-tests-that-use-http), you should try :

```
$httpBackend.flush();
```

Comment: Yes it's true, and just to clarify : it should be done after the $http call.